# check if name from table 1 exists in table 2

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i searched on google but i could not find it(maybe wrong search terms) But i'm asking if there is a way to check if name1 from table 1 exists in table 2

So like

select name from table 1.

search in table 2 for the name from table 1

is this possible? if yes how?

~Kev (bad english = sorry)

Comment: What is the structure of table 2?

Comment: Can you provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with both tables' structures?

Comment: @eggyal the same as table 1

Comment: Please add the exact table structure, example data, expected output and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `INNER JOIN` using `name` do the trick?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/036f84

Comment: With *exact stable structure* I meant the relevant parts for the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out this...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.name in (SELECT table2.name FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select name from table1 Inner Join table2 on table1.name = table2.name;
```

Depending on your structure this will give you all the names which exists both in table1 and  table2 since the joining is done itself on the name

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (untested)

SELECT name1 FROM tableA WHERE name1= (SELECT name2 FROM table2 WHERE .... )

Comment: Is this also possible for multiple row's?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about joins between 2 tables. To query all entries from table 1 that exists in table 2 you need next SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s2="select * from trackyesttrackyest";
$q2=mysql_query($s2) or die($s2);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q2);

$s="select * from <secondtablename> where rsname='".$row['rsname']."'";
$q=mysql_query($s) or die($s);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

Answer (score 1):

please refer this link

[click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;

Its simple buddy.........